# error while installing ocamlfind.1.3.3 configure: m4 not in PATH; this is required

Tags: ocaml, m4, ocamlfind

configure: m4 not in PATH; this is required

I wonder how I can fix this.

Thanks a lot!
(I tried to copy the m4 folder to that path but it is not working)

```
==== ERROR [while installing ocamlfind.1.3.3] ====
# opam-version    1.0.0
# os              linux
# command         ./configure -bindir /home/airobert/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/bin -sitelib                   /home/airobert/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/lib -mandir /home/airobert/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/man -config /home/airobert/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/lib/findlib.conf
# path            /home/airobert/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/build/ocamlfind.1.3.3
# exit-code       1
# env-file        /home/airobert/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/build/ocamlfind.1.3.3/ocamlfind-5f1023.env
# stdout-file     /home/airobert/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/build/ocamlfind.1.3.3/ocamlfind-5f1023.out
# stderr-file     /home/airobert/.opam/4.01.0dev+trunk/build/ocamlfind.1.3.3/ocamlfind-5f1023.err
### stdout ###
Welcome to findlib version 1.3.3
Configuring core...
### stderr ###
configure: m4 not in PATH; this is required

'opam install ocamlfind' failed.
```

Answer (score 13):

Is m4 installed on your system?

If you use a debian-based linux, try `sudo apt-get install m4`.